# Got "expecting CLOSE, found '=' " exception when tried to use SUM with HAVING in HQL

Tags: mysql, hql

I'm rewriting my JDBC query in HQL.

For each job I have a workflow and there are a few tasks for each workflow.
Tasks can be of types '0', '1', '2', and '3' and have a BOOL column 'completed'. Each workflow has at least one task of each type. I need to fetch only those jobs, workflows of which have only tasks of type '0' being completed.

Here's my JDBC query:

```
"SELECT j.*

FROM job j

INNER JOIN workflow w

ON j.id = w.job_id

INNER JOIN task t

ON t.workflow_id = w.id

WHERE j.company_id = ?

GROUP BY j.id

HAVING SUM(t.completed = TRUE AND t.type != 0) = 0"
```

Here's my HQL query:

```
"SELECT j

FROM Job j

JOIN c.workflow w

JOIN task t

WHERE j.company_id = :companyId

GROUP BY j.id

HAVING SUM(t.completed = TRUE AND t.type != 0) = 0"
```

However running this HQL query gives me "expecting CLOSE, found '='" exception for SUM clause.

Comment: Use `HAVING SUM(t.completed) = TRUE AND t.type != 0`

Comment: I appreciate your comment Tim but unfortunately that doesn't return the result I need. It appeared that my HQL query contains a lot of errors except the already mentioned one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer after a few hours of struggling. Here's the working query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT j
FROM Job j, Workflow w, Task t
WHERE w.job.id = j.id AND
t.workflow.id = w.id AND
j.company.id = ? AND
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Task t
WHERE t.workflow.id = w.id AND
t.completed = TRUE AND
t.type != 0) = 0"
```